# Is there any linux command to get number of context switches for a process?

Tags: linux, process

Is there any Linux command to get various information like context switches of a process? Any solution other than ps will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A context switch counters are in `/proc/$$/status`:

As an example:

`voluntary_ctxt_switches:        230
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches:     35`

You can get this easily by doing something similar to:

`$ grep ctxt /proc/1234/status`

Comment: Interesting. I tried on few pid but they have no ctxt value. Will try on more pid. There is another command (#command pid) which shows useful information (context switch is one of them) just like the stat (#stat filename) command. It was a very nice utility which i forgot :(

Comment: If you want rolling stats, look at pidstat -w 1